# two different projects with the same package name for apk

Tags: android, package, apk

is there any consideration to take into account when I would like to generate apk file from the different project with the same package name? I'm using the keystore path of the old project and would like to update my app into a different one, whose source code is from the project I created in addition to the old one. Thanks.

EDIT
I got the following error when uploading to APK
[image]

Comment: You have to make the same package name in your projects. Look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package).

Comment: make sure persistent stuff are correctly migrated (or deleted) by the new app. That includes mostly files, sqlite db, preferences. if your main activity's name changes, shortcuts will stop working.

Comment: can you check my edited blog again? I may assume wrongly that the package name has something to do with the error above. Also, the jks file name that I am using for apk is different from the name of the project

Comment: @user2585578 Hey i also facing same issue. Did you got any solution?